# Is it possible to combine SLAAC for address assignment with DHCPv6 for dynamic DNS?

Tags: dhcpv6

Is it possible to use DHCPv6 for dynamic DNS registration in a network where SLAAC is used for address assignment (i.e. both the "Managed Address Configuration" and the "Other Configuration" flags are set)?

The RFCs (for both SLAAC and DHCPv6) don't really seem to mention this specific use case, so I wonder if this is

- Possible at all (i.e. is it possible to combine the FQDN DHCPv6 option with an already-assigned SLAAC address)?
- Commonly supported by client operating systems and DHCP (combined with local DNS) servers?

Update:
It seems that dnsmasq, for example, [supports](https://community.ui.com/questions/what-is-going-on-with-slaac-dnsmasq/abe4611c-e309-42a3-a02e-7e3a726a544e) a heuristic that assumes that an IPv6 host will always assume an SLAAC address based on its MAC address. However, this will not work for hosts implementing [RFC 7217](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7217), for example.

Comment: Short answer: yes (I'm sure I've done it) but why (I did it to get around a strange bug with Windows)?

Comment: I've come to like being able to effectively define my device's local hostname (e.g. `device.lan`), where `device` is the client id(?) configured in the DHCP client/network settings. Saves me a trip to the DHCP server to set up a MAC<->hostname binding there.